# Why is setOverrideDeadline not respected?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I use the following code to schedule a job when the network becomes available:

```
static JobScheduler jobScheduler(Context context) {
    return (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
}

static JobInfo jobInfo(Context context, Date nextTime) {
    return new JobInfo.Builder((int) R.string.action_send_mail, new ComponentName(context, MessageJobService.class))
                .setMinimumLatency(max(0, nextTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setOverrideDeadline(15 * 1000)
                .setBackoffCriteria(5000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .build();
};

public static void scheduleNextJob(Context context) {
    MailMessage mailMessage = DbHelper.inContext(context).loadNextMessage();

    if(mailMessage != null) {
        jobScheduler(context).schedule(jobInfo(context, mailMessage.getNextAttempt()));
    }
}
```

My understanding of `setOverrideDeadline` is that my job will fire after 5 seconds when the network becomes available, or no later than 15 seconds.  In practice, if I enable airline mode, and run `scheduleNextJob` the job never fires until the I disable airline mode.

At that point, within my job, `isOverrideDeadlineExpired` is true, so I'm pretty sure the deadline is being set, it just doesn't seem to be respected.

Why is the override deadline not being respected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the combination of `setMinimumLatency(0)` and `setOverrideDeadline` doesn't work as expected.  Changing the minimum latency to at least 1 seems to solve the problem:

```
static JobInfo jobInfo(Context context, Date nextTime) {
    return new JobInfo.Builder((int) R.string.action_send_mail, new ComponentName(context, MessageJobService.class))
                .setMinimumLatency(max(1, nextTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setOverrideDeadline(15 * 1000)
                .setBackoffCriteria(5000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .build();
};
```

Comment: Hi just curious can we update every minute using this JobScheduler?